# Workflow Approval

Tags: designer-workflow, workflow-variable

I have attached a workflow to a form ( with infopath ).
I need to add a condition in Sharepoint designer 2010 ( Workflow Approval ) : like this :

If List Purchase Orders: Total Price is greather than 50000
Start Process Approval team1 on ..... with approvers 
Else Start Process Approval team2 on ..... with approvers

The problem is in the  condition , I dont know how to customize this condition:
How to check the value filled in the form (field:Total price) and compare it if it's greather or less than 50000 ?

Answer (score 0):

In the infopath form, you'll need to publish the total price field. Once it's published, it will show up in the list, and you'll be able to access it via a sharepoint designer condition.

First, publish the field:
http://support.formotus.com/entries/20514141-How-to-promote-fields-in-InfoPath-2010

Then, if sharepoint designer is still open, you'll have to refresh the site (hit the refresh button in designer, or close and reopen designer.

Comment: thank you for your reactivity , yes its published , everything its ok , its showed up ,but i dont know how to fill  the condition !!